# transform JSON file to be usable

Tags: python, json, api

Long story short, i get the query from spotify api which is JSON that has data about newest albums. How do i get the specific info from that like let's say every band name or every album title. I've tried a lot of ways to get that info that i found on the internet and nothing seems to work for me and after couple of hours im kinda frustrated
JSON data is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5vn2ge8/)
***here is the request***

```py
endpoint = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases"
lookup_url = f"{endpoint}"
r = requests.get(lookup_url, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

you can find the

Comment: It's a dictionary... you just access the keys you want.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: r.json() will return a dicitonary object that you can access like a normal python dictionary. If its relevant you can learn about the dedicated JSON library here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html and about dictionaries in python here: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: yeah, can you show me how to get let's say the name of the artist and i don't wanna any links to "how to get key value pair" i wanna see how to operate on this specific data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make this request like the comments have mentioned you get a dictionary which you can then access the keys and values. For example if you want to get the `album_type` you could do the following:

```py
print(data["albums"]["items"][0]["album_type"])
```

Since `items` contains a list you would need to get the first values `0` and then access the `album_type`.

#### Output:

```
single
```

[Here is a link to the code I used with your json.](https://pastebin.com/HUfcEUyW)

I suggest you look into how to deal with json data in python, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I) is a good place to start.

Answer (score -1):

I copied the data from the jsfiddle link.

Now try the following code:

```
import ast
pyobj=ast.literal_eval(str_cop_from_src)
```

later you can try with keys

```
pyobj["albums"]["items"][0]["album_type"]
```

pyobj will be a python dictionary will all data.